# Django meta declaration in models

Tags: python, django

I don't know if there is any difference between these two `Meta` declarations:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    #...

    class Meta(object):  # <------- (1)
       #...

    class Meta:          # <------- (2)
       #...
```

Which one is correct and preferred? Does it depend on the usage?

I use python 2 and 3, and Django 1.7+.

Comment: I've never seen the first example `Meta(object)` used. Where did you get it from?

Comment: I have a source code which uses python 2.7 and Django 1.7. It uses the first one to declare `verbose_name` and `verbose_name_plural`. It works.

Answer (score 2):

Classes which don't inherit from anything are called old-style classes

```
class old_style:
    pass
```

Other classes which inherit from object are called new-style classes

```
class new_style(object):
    pass
```

classes who inherit from new-style classes are also new-style because at the end they inherit from object:

```
class new_style(object):
    pass

class new_style2(new_style):
    pass
```

In python 3, all classes are new classes(inherit from object), therefore in python 3:

```
class e(object):
    pass

class d:
    pass
```

e == d

You can read more about their differences/usages in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python)

Comment: So, you say both of them are the same in action? This [official reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/) is using the old-style.

Comment: New-style classes contain some bulit-in methods/attributes but they are slower to create, old-style classes only contains __doc__ and __module__ but they are much more faster to create ---- You can read more in the question I've linked ---- If you're using python 3 then just ignore all of this, since old-style classes only exist in python 2